# Show that the diagonal map maps X homeomorphically onto the diagonal

Tags: general-topology, continuity, product-space

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $ ∆ = \{(x; x) : x ∈ X\}$ be the diagonal of $X$.

Deﬁne  $f: X → X × X$ by $f(x) = (x; x)$. Show that $f$ maps $X$ homeomorphically
onto $ ∆$.

Comment: To show it's a homeomorphism $X \cong \Delta$, you need to check that it maps onto $\Delta$, that the map is bijective, that it's continuous, and that its inverse is continuous. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Shimaa.  Perhaps you are just learning these terms and need some help with the definitions.  Clive's comment sufficiently describes the notion of [homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism), but it might also be helpful to first review the idea of [continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Continuous_functions_between_topological_spaces) for topological spaces.  It will also be necessary to know about the [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) given to a product of two topological spaces.

Comment: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.": the closers might want to explain what they mean. Obviously, none of the above apply.

Answer (score 2):

Showing that map to be bijective is trivial. Note that any $\Delta$-open set can without loss of generality be written as the union of sets of the form $\Delta\cap(U\times U)$,  where $U$ is $X$-open. This follows from the definition of the product topology on $X\times X$, and from the topology it induces on $\Delta$ as a subspace (plus a bit of finagling). This will make it easier to show continuity. Also, the image of any $X$-open set $U$ under the map is equal to $\Delta\cap(U \times U)$, which can be shown without much difficulty, and from that it follows that the map is open.